# Unable to load R package "adabag"

Tags: r

I installed 'adabag' package in R (2.14.2) successfully but when I load it I get the following error:

```
Loading required package: caret
Error : object 'parallelplot' not found whilst loading namespace 'caret'
Error: package ‘caret’ could not be loaded
```

I am not sure if 'parallelplot' is a package. I tried to install 'parallelplot' package too but it's not available for R version 2.14.2.
Could anyone help me fix this problem?

Comment: I have tried reinstalling 'caret'. I get the same error when I load it separately.

Comment: How did you install adabag? From CRAN? From source? What OS?

Comment: Try upgrading R to 12.15.2.

Comment: Upgraded R to 2.15.2 and it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on R v. 2.14.2 and I resolved it by installing the package `lattice`

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this reply, but this worked for me.

...
install.packages("robustbase"), then (assuming that is successful), restart R and try loading adabag again.

ef
https://community.rstudio.com/t/i-am-having-trouble-loading-adabag-package/16252